# React Delete element: "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component"

Tags: graphql, react-typescript

I have a page displayin a list of data in Card(s) element.
On page loadin, all "Cards" are loaded with a useQuery.
Any "Card" can be edited, deleted, and there is a button to create a new one.
I use a state to display the list of results loaded from GraphQl (Appolo client).

When deleting a "Card" (from mutation call) diplayed list if correcty re rendered bu I have a React warning "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component"

Can someone explain me the issue and how it is possible to solve it ?

[image]
Sample Code

```
  const {data: indicatorsData} = queryIndicators()
  const {createQueryIndicator} = createQueryIndicatorMutation()
  const {deleteQueryIndicator} = deleteQueryIndicatorMutation()

  const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = useState(false)
  const [form] = useForm()
  const [displayedQueryIndicators, setDisplayedQueryIndicators] =
      useState<QueryIndicator[]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (indicatorsData) {
      setDisplayedQueryIndicators(() => indicatorsData.queryIndicators)
    }
  }, [indicatorsData])
```

........

```
 const handleCancel = () => {
    setIsOpened(false)
 }

  const handleDeleteIndicator = (uuid: any) => {
    deleteQueryIndicator({variables: {uuid}})
    .then(result => {
      const newList = displayedQueryIndicators.filter(
          indicator => indicator.uuid !== result.data.deleteQueryIndicator)
      setDisplayedQueryIndicators(newList)
    })
    .catch((info) => {console.log(info)})
  }
```

..........

```
      <Row gutter={12}>
                  <Col span={8}>
                    <EditOutlined onClick={() => console.log("")} key="edit"/>
                  </Col>
                  <Col span={8}>
                    <RedoOutlined onClick={() => console.log("")} key="refresh"/>
                  </Col>
                  <Col span={8}>
                    <Popconfirm
                        placement="top" title={'Are you sure ?'}
                        onConfirm={() => handleDeleteIndicator(indicator.uuid)}
                        okText="Yes"
                        cancelText="No"
                    >
                      <DeleteOutlined onClick={() => console.log("")} key="delete"/>
                    </Popconfirm>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
```

[image]

Comment: Where you are using `handleDeleteIndicator`? What other `useEffects` are related to the problem? I think there is not enough context to answer your question fully.

Comment: In your screenshot the error states it is coming from `PopupInner` - is this wthin a Card? Likely it has state changing after the card is removed and it is unmounted.

Comment: I've updated to sample code.
handleDeleteIndicator is called by the PopupConfirm validation.
I have only one useEffect Block based on the IndicatorsData (a list returned from backend)

Comment: Issue comes after deleting the card and updating the "displayIndidators" state list

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found to avoid this warning is to set a timeout like this
I do not believe it's a good solution but it works.

```
const handleDeleteIndicator = (uuid: any) => {
  deleteQueryIndicator({variables: {uuid}})
  .then(result => {
    setTimeout(() =>
        setDisplayedQueryIndicators((prevState) =>
            displayedQueryIndicators.filter(
                indicator => indicator.uuid !== result.data.deleteQueryIndicator)
        ),
        100
    )
  })
  .catch((info) => {console.log(info)})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any way it seems it's not really a problem, according to React team itemseft which remove this warning on React 18.
See here: https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/82